# firefox 17 location.constructor exception

Tags: javascript, firefox, typeof

Trying to access `location.constructor` in firefox 17 (Ubuntu) throws an error `InternalError: too much recursion` ([bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=814622)).

I'm walking over all own properties of window (i.e. global variables) and want to filter out system objects like `location`, `localStorage` etc. I check, that property's constructor is not equal to `Date`, `Array` or `Object`.

The question is: could one suggest another technique to do the same w/o accessing `constructor` property? Working in Chrome/FF is enough.

Comment: There would be many objects whose `constructor` property is not `Date`/`Array`/`Object`, how do think you could filter out system objects by that?

Comment: I hardly need objects like `jQuery` as well.

Answer (score 1):

It might work to check for Object.getPrototypeOf(whatever) being Object.prototype, Array.prototype, or Date.prototype.